# We cannot create an std::array from an initializer_list, but can we create it with a helper function with variadic arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Please consider the following `vector` class:

```
template<typename T, class Tuple = std::vector<T>>
class vector
{
public:
    using size_type = typename Tuple::size_type;

    template<class T = Tuple, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T, size_type>::value>>
    vector(size_type n)
        : m_elements(n)
    { }
    template<class T = Tuple, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T, std::initializer_list<T>>::value>>
    vector(std::initializer_list<T> init)
        : m_elements(init)
    { }

private:
    Tuple m_elements;
}; // class vector

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
using static_vector = vector<T, std::array<T, N>>;

template<typename T>
static_vector<T, /* N */> make_static_vector(T... elements) { /* ... */ }
```

The problem is that I want to use `std::array` for `Tuple`, but `std::array` is not constructible from an `initialiter_list`. That's why I've disabled the corresponding constructor of `vector` in that case. (I know that I could use `std::copy(init.begin(), init.end(), m_elements.begin()` in either case, but that would yield other problems.)

Since I would like to do something like `static_vector<double> x = { 1, 2, 3 };` I thought my best option (feel free to correct me) to provide a helper function like `make_static_vector`. (That's not as beautiful as an `initializer_list`, so, again, please feel free to come up with a more beautiful solution.)

I want to write `auto x = make_static_vector<double>(1, 2, 3);`. How do I need to implement it?

Comment: This is valid indeed: `std::array<int, 3> a2 = {1, 2, 3};`. This one as well (in C++11, using C++14 you don't need double braces): `std::array<int, 3> a1{ {1, 2, 3} };`. See the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: @skypjack this is a braced init list, OP talks about `std::initializer_list`

Comment: You are right, I simply tried to go over and figure out the goal. That's all. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple form looks like this:

```
template <typename T,typename... Elements>
static_vector<T, sizeof...(Elements)>
  make_static_vector(Elements... elements)
{
    return static_vector<T,sizeof...(Elements)>(elements...);
}
```

You will also need to make a variadic constructor for your vector:

```
template <typename... Args>
vector(Args... init)
    : m_elements{static_cast<T>(init)...}
{ }
```

The `static_cast` is necessary if you want to avoid narrowing errors using ints where doubles are required.

If you want to use perfect forwarding, it's a bit more to type, but it's the same idea.

Comment: Why *should* I or might *want* to use perfect forwarding instead?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: If you are making a vector of large objects which can be efficiently moved but not efficiently copied, then using perfect forwarding may give better performance.

Comment: What *exactly* would I need to change? I guess  `make_static_vector(Elements&&... elements) { return static_vector<T, sizeof...(Elements)>(std::forward<Elements>(elements)...); }`. Anything else?

Comment: And let me add a further question: You've written that *the suitable constructor has been created*. What do you mean with that? It sounds like the compiler has implicitly created that constructor (of course, that's not true). I suppose you mean that I need to provide that constructor.
In the pressence of that constructor, do I still need the `initializer_list` constructor? I assume not. `static_cast<T>(elements)...` should be converted to `initializer_list<T>` and hence the `initializer_list<T>` constructor of `Tuple` (if available) should be called.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: You would also need to perfect-forward the constructor.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: The "suitable constructor" is the one that I gave just below.  It is taking a variable number of parameters instead of an `initializer_list`.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: I've edited the answer.  Maybe that is a little clearer.

Comment: Perhaps you want to make the variadic constructor SFINAE-able, in case list-initialization is not supported by `Tuple` (other constructors are) ?

Comment: So, I need `vector(Elements&&... elements) : m_elements{ static_cast<T>(std::forward<Elements>(elements))... }`, too, right? What do you think about the other question? Do I still need the `initializer_list` constructor?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki What *exactly* do you mean?

Comment: @0xbadf00d all you constructors are sfinae-friendly, then maybe [make this one as well](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e8bac316d89d1b4)

Comment: @0xbadf00d:  The `initializer_list` constructor isn't needed for `make_static_vector`, but you may needed it for something else.

Comment: @VaughnCato Why? For example, `std::vector` doesn't have a constructor of the form considered here, but an `initializer_list` constructor. Writing `vector<double> x = { 1, 2, 3 };` should invoke the `initializer_list` constructor of `std::vector` at `m_elements{ static_cast<T>(std::forward<Elements>(elements))... }`. [Here is an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0e100077fec83de).

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Perhaps you want to forward an `initializer_list` in some cases:  `make_someother_vector({1,2,3})`.  You can certainly remove the `initializer_list` constructor if you don't need it.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Good point, thanks. But there is something I don't understand. Please take a look at the following [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c561c45c75255258) and take notice of the comments in `main`.

Comment: @VaughnCato I'm not sure, if I got your point, but would you agree that in the given case I don't need the the `initializer_list` constructor of `vector` in the presence of the other one?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: In your example, you have narrowing due to passing `int`s instead of `double`s.

Comment: @VaughnCato Yes, I know. (That's why I've added the comment "Error as expected" to the fourth line in `main`). The line I'm wondering about is the second one.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: I was also talking about the second one.  It's the same problem.  If you pass `double`s instead of ints, it works: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7af9a301583daf8

Comment: @VaughnCato I've upvoted your answer, but at least two users downvoted it. Have you any idea why?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Your suggested solution doesn't work if we replace `make_static_vector<int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);` by `make_static_vector<double>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);`. The problem is, that in that case `Tuple` is not constructible from `std::declval<Ts>()...` and hence the constructor is disabled. How do I need to change the code? At least `m_elements{ std::forward<Ts>(ts)... }` must be replaced by `m_elements{ static_cast<T>(std::forward<Ts>(ts))... }`, but I don't know how I need to change the template parameter.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Here is a complete example using perfect forwarding:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4cb92938a29ffca1

Comment: @VaughnCato My question was related to PiotrSkotnicki's suggested modification of the constructor. I've [edited your example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12df9ebfebaa434c) which now produces the compiler error I've mentioned.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: I see.  You can do this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80b6ef5adad27931

Comment: @VaughnCato What's the use of `static_cast<void>(x);`? Now, `vector<double> x(2);` [won't call the `vector::vector(size_type)` constructor](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4b681883d79b1e8). The reason is plausible, but I would like to provide that constructor too. What can I do?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: `static_cast<void>(x)` is to avoid a warning about `x` not being used.

Comment: @0xbadf00d:  It's not using that constructor because `U` is not used: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/138f36197429d9e7

Comment: @VaughnCato Can you explain what exactly is going on? `T` is defaulted to type `T = Tuple`. Why is `T = size_type` whenever the constructor is enabled?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Probably better in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105260/discussion-between-vaughn-cato-and-0xbadf00d